# Python asyncore with UDP

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, tcp, udp, asyncore

Can I write an UDP client/server application in asyncore? I have already written one using TCP. My desire is to integrate it with support for UDP.

My question was not previously asked/answered by the following:
[Python asyncore UDP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424848/python-asyncore-udp-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Here is a simple example:

```py
class AsyncoreSocketUDP(asyncore.dispatcher):

  def __init__(self, port=0):
    asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
    self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.bind(('', port))

  # This is called every time there is something to read
  def handle_read(self):
    data, addr = self.recvfrom(2048)
    # ... do something here, eg self.sendto(data, (addr, port))

  def writable(self): 
    return False # don't want write notifies
```

That should be enough to get you started. Have a look inside the `asyncore` module for more ideas.

Minor note: `asyncore.dispatcher` sets the socket as non blocking. If
you want to write a lot of data quickly to the socket without causing
errors you'll have to do some application-dependent buffering
ala `asyncore.dispatcher_with_send`.

Thanks to the (slightly inaccurate) code here for getting me started:
https://www.panda3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9364

Comment: Thanks for the `self.sendto(data, (addr, port))`

Answer (score 1):

After long search the answer is **no**. Asyncore assumes the underlying socket is connection-oriented, i.e. TCP.

Answer (score 1):

Hi thanks @bw1024 for pointing in the right direction, I will add my solution inspired by yours , pandas and the python asyncore documentation.

My use case is capturing some JSON from a UDP stream

`

import socket
import json
import asyncore

UDP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
UDP_PORT = 2000

class AsyncUDPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):
def **init**(self, host, port):
asyncore.dispatcher.**init**(self)
self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
self.bind((host, port))
print("connecting.. host = '{0}'' port = '{1}'" .format(host, str(port)))

```
def handle_connect(self):
    print("connected")


def handle_read(self):
    data = self.recv(1024)
    y = json.loads(data)
    print("PM 2.5 ug/m^3 async : %s "% y['PM25MassPerM3'])

def writable(self):
    return False;
```

client = AsyncUDPClient(UDP_IP, UDP_PORT)

asyncore.loop()

`

P.S not sure why the code is not correctly being formatted its running on python 3.6.9 OK here is a [link](https://gist.github.com/ganindu7/d85dc47a1849c6281f5e65558b2e346f) to a gist