# How to implement UDP and TCP socket using AsyncIo

Tags: python, tcp, udp, python-asyncio

So technically I have already created a TCP listening socket and everything works fine.

It simply get tcp json message and spit it out.

```
class TCPListener(Base):
    def __init__(self,
                 address,
                 port,
                 buffer,
                 backlog,
                 **kwargs):
        self.tcp_address = address
        self.tcp_port = port
        self.tcp_buffer = buffer
        self.tcp_asyncio_backlog = backlog
        self.queue = queue.Queue()

    def __await__(self):
        self._server = yield from asyncio.start_server(
            self.__on_message,
            host=self.tcp_address,
            port=self.tcp_port,
            backlog=self.tcp_asyncio_backlog
        )
        return self

    async def __on_message(self, reader, writer):
        message = await reader.read(self.tcp_buffer)
        try:
            json_encoded = json.loads(message.decode('UTF-8').strip())
            self.queue.put(json_encoded)
        writer.close()

    def start(self):
        loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
        asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
        asyncio.ensure_future(self, loop=loop)


    def receive(self):
        while self.queue.empty():
            sleep_random = random.randint(0, 1000)
            time.sleep(sleep_random / 1000.0)

        if not self.queue.empty():
            return self.queue.get(block=False)
        return '', ''
```

Now I am trying to make this code to work for both TCP and UDP listener. I wonder what function I can keep and how I share them between both Listener, kinda clueless for how to approch this ! If I am not mistaken I should use "create_datagram_endpoint" but still have no idea how glue it with this class and functions.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48625510/1600898) help?

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a way to combine them more and reuse the variables. I can simply write another class for UDP, but that's not my intention .

Comment: what functionality do you want to share?  UDP and TCP have pretty different semantics.  also, why is `receive` doing that strange randomised `sleep` thing rather than just blocking in `queue.get`?

Comment: In short I want to have one class that handle both TCP and UDP (maybe this is not a ideal way to do it, but I am not sure) or I should create two seperate class with different thread calling each one of them. Your suggestion is apperciated. for receive part it's to Return one message dequeued from the listen buffer at a time.